# Insert Select Where Primary Key is selecting every record

Tags: mysql, select, insert, primary-key, where-clause

I'm attempting to copy a record from one table to another (and eventually deleting the original with one click) I basically have a repair tracking page, when those repairs are completed I want to remove that record by filling a checkbox and clicking the submit button, and move that record to the archive/history table. I've been successful in copying the records, however every record is copied, I'm guessing the issue is related to my WHERE clause

```
mysql_select_db("testmoverecord", $con);
$id = $_POST['checkbox'];
$sql =("INSERT INTO history (id, firstname, lastname, age)
SELECT repair.id, repair.firstname, repair.lastname, repair.age FROM repair
WHERE id = $id");

echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' value='{$row['id']}' name='checkbox'";
```

How do I pass the ID correctly? I tried WHERE repair.id = history.id but it says Unknown column even though it exists. I've tried putting in a hidden input for id and posting the id but haven't got those to work. I'm using mysql, it's open to injection blah blah blah, save yourself the typing, I plan on updating soon, it cannot be touched remotely and its storing data that isn't even close to being sensitive so I don't mind. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks for any assistance.

EDITED: This code works

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO history (id, firstname, lastname, age)
    SELECT * FROM repair
    WHERE id = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($id));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, using the % sign I can get to a point where there are no errors, however nothing is entered into the second table. I'm not sure why??

Comment: Instead of "SELECT *", make sure you are selecting the correct fields in the correct order of your INSERT statement.  For example:  "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, age"

Comment: Hmm, I've put in SELECT repair.id, repair.firstname, repair.lastname, repair.age FROM repair, same results, still no errors, yet nothing is entered into the second table, I'm not sure what else I could provide that would be relevant, again thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Are you assigning a value to $id?  If so, does that record exist in repair?  Try your query in a standalone tool first to make sure it works, then port it to php.

Comment: If I use WHERE id = 1"); it works, but I need it to be dynamic, so I've definitely gone wrong somewhere in my attempt for the value to equal any checked box, I'll do some more research.

Comment: You need to assign a value to the variable $id.  Take my code and assign 1 to $id: "$id = 1;"

Comment: Thanks for your last response, you were spot on, I gave my checkbox an id, then posted the id and it works, although if I want to do multiple checkboxes I'm guessing I'll have to use an array. If you want to add another answer with the actual fix, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks again!!

Comment: Now you changed your question to something else.  It would have been better to accept the answer to the original question, then ask another question on how to post multiple inputs.

Comment: I asked "How do I pass the ID correctly?" the answer was to give my checkbox an id, the question never changed. Sorry but your first answer is not relevant to my question. As I said, if  you want to supply another answer relevant to my question, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You forgot that you changed your original query sample code from "where id = id" to the format that I suggested (using the $id syntax, which solved your original problem).